# How to restore file to some earlier stage?

Tags: windows

I have a windows application whose data is stored in xml file. Due to insufficient knowledge of the program, my employee deleted the entire data/records in the xml file by running clear command in the application.

Is there a way, I can restore the file to it's earlier state, say 1 day or two days ago ? The operating system in use is windows xp and the application was developed uses foxpro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Windows XP has no built in version control, nor does FoxPro.  Without proper backups, you are out of luck.

Comment: Don't have any backup. May be that was a big mistake

Comment: BTW when you mentioned XP has no built in version control, does this mean that Windows 7 support this facility ??

Comment: Win 7 does have have a version control system tied to the system restore functionality.  Its not the most convenient thing to use.  You are better off using a real backup program.

Answer (score 0):

You can recommend recovery software to your customers. Just google **recover deleted files**. Most of this tools are shareware.

But it is not warranty about 100% recovery.

Comment: Recovery software works better  when a file's been deleted - I think he deleted the data, and left the file intact. You might also want to improve your answer by suggesting *specific* file recovery software you know works , rather than suggesting google

Comment: @gavekoa, The file has not been deleted. It exists with no records.